# App crashes: class has no empty constructor

Tags: java, android

Getting the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class appname.PlayerSelection; no empty constructor
```

I have been reading about this for hours and none of the solutions offered apply to me.  The app was working fine yesterday, I made some changes unrelated to anything at all (added a void method to the class, then removed it again after it broke).

I have deleted the activity from the manifest file and re-added it from scratch, the manifest file states that the class has no default constructor.

It is set up exactly the same way as all my other activities, the constructor is simple:

```
public class PlayerSelection extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
```

I tried deleting and re-adding the onCreate method.... nothing at all is working.  Why does it think it has no constructor now, when it was working before and it clearly has one?

Please help :(

Update:  after adnan9011 helped me below, I am getting a nullpointer exception error on the class at the bottom line below:

```
public class PlayerSelection extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {

private AdView mAdView;
private final static String config="Config.txt";
final Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
*final ImageButton btnP1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayer1);*
```

I deleted this line and retyped it, to see if it finds the reference by itself, and it finds R.id.btnPlayer1 without a problem.   Ugh...

Comment: Please share `PlayerSelection` code

Comment: Activities are created for you by framework, you request that by `Intent`s. You will NEVER call an activity constructor yourself. If you did, you did something wrong. So delete all constructors and let it assume one empty public.

Comment: Also you may just have an extra curly brace somewhere.

Comment: Hi Mithun.   The whole thing?  It is very, very large.

Comment: @adnun9011 - what answer mate?  You haven't posed one.

Comment: @Eugen - Thanks for your response mate, but I have no idea what you are saying.  All of my activities are generated in exactly the same way.  They all work perfectly, including this one, until yesterday.   The app is saying I do NOT have a constructor, not that I have too many.  How can I not have one?

Comment: There's a window called "Structure" in Android Studio. Open it and really check that there's no `PlayerSelection` method. Try doing a clean build. If you know exactly when it started happening compare the file with its version from VCS when it was still working and find the error.

Comment: `g = (Globals)getApplication()` belongs after `super.onCreate(...)`. `btnP1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayer1)` belongs after `setContentView(...)`. Otherwise they will be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete **method (constructor)** of your class that name is `PlayerSelection()`

because `PlayerSelection` extends of `Activity` , that don't need of constructors .

your class should be **like this**:

```
public class PlayerSelection extends Activity {

}
```

**Not like this:**

```
public class PlayerSelection extends Activity {
    public PlayerSelection() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for your reply but my class is exactly like you say it should be.   It is exactly the first example, and nothing like the second example at all.

Comment: @Bisclavret then post your class

Comment: Wow... you were right man.  I had not created a constructor like you had suggested, but I did a search through it anyway just to be sure.  Android Studio had created a separate constructor on it's own that held the declarations for bitmaps I was trying to create....... I removed this constructor and that error message went away.   I have a new one now though:

Comment: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{touchpool/touchpool.PlayerSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException.    I will add the line it is pointing at in an edit on the main question.

Comment: @Bisclavret , post your logcat .

Comment: Fixed it all up mate, moved chunks of stuff around, didn't make sense but everything works now.   Thank you so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use constructors for `Activites` in Android, this is bad and will cause a lot of trouble like this error. Remove any constructor you made from every subclass of `Activity`.

Also never do this `PlayerSelection someSelection = new PlayerSelection();` Android forbids manual substantiation of Services/Activities

Comment: Hi Bojan, thanks for your reply mate.   I have absolutely no idea what this means.  How can I remove a constructor?   The entire problem is that it thinks that it does not have one in the first place....... so I HAVE to use one, yes?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use any constructors. Nor should you try to manually instantiate Activity classes, check if you have done that anywhere or post more code, I can't see what is going on mate